# What does language-neutral mean?

Tags: meaning

Could anyone please tell me what is this word means?

> The ISO 8601 is not language-neutral for the DateTime datatype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Language-neutral*, in this context, means "applies equally to all languages".

So, ISO 8601 does not apply equally to all languages for the DateTime datatype.

Comment: Can I say it means `doesn't matter with language` or `the different languages doesn't impact on it `? thanks.

Comment: @Joe no, you can't. Neither is English.

Comment: And apart from that, the suggested rephrasings mean the _opposite_ of what the text says. It says that it DOES matter what language we are talking about here.